# difference between 'git svn rebase' and 'git rebase trunk'

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, rebase

I am using git-svn for my project.

What is the difference between `git svn rebase` and `git rebase trunk`?

Is `git svn rebase` run on master basically the same as `git rebase trunk` run on master?

Answer (score 4):

No. `git svn rebase` is equivalent to running the following:

```
git svn fetch --parent
git rebase remotes/trunk
```

(That assumes the Git branch you're working on is based off `remotes/trunk`; if it's based off a different Subversion branch, it will rebase onto the correct branch.)

The difference is that `git svn rebase` pulls the latest code from Subversion before doing the rebase, and it also automatically works out the correct remote branch to rebase against.